# How do I prove to users that something is safe?

Tags: python, security

Sorry if this seems like some simple question to lots of people. But basically I was working on some rotation calculator for a game I play - for fun. I thought why not share it with the gaming community in reddit in the form of a .exe so everyone could use it (without have to install python and made using Pyinstaller). I understand the risk of malware .. which is my problem. Short story short it got removed with the following message:

" As pointed out in the comments, alot of players are careful about what they click on. If it's not a known download they use they will report it which in turn means it gets removed."

I know this is safe, but i have no way to prove to others it is, which is where i'm stuck. What can i do about this?

Comment: You can check that very file for viruses on a service called Virustotal, and then provide a link to its report alongside the download link. Virustotal can also scan files _you give it a link to_: you upload your file to some file sharing service, get the link to it and let Virustotal analyze this link and the file itself, then post the download link and the link to the Virustotal report. Then people _may_ trust you, but some still may not.

Comment: Publish it in source code form, so people can inspect it and compile it for themselves. By the way, I highly doubt you actually *know* it is safe. You believe so, but how certain can you be you don't have malware sitting on your system, unbeknownst to you, inserting itself into your program?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I didn't know about Virustotal either so thanks for that :) you are potentially correct about malware on my system, but you could say that for anyone (means lots would be screwed) - and using avira doing regular scans i should hopefully be okay. As for the source code idea, i'm fine sharing that i will just need to clean it up a bit first :D

Comment: Consider publishing a SHA256 signature of the file you're offering somewhere, e.g. in the Reddit community. Then everyone who obtains a copy of your .exe could check that it's the copy you published, not something altered.